# How to update a Docker container from a newer image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a project with the following file structure:

```
- Dockerfile
- app/
    - file.txt
    - uploads/
```

The `file.txt` file contains *Hello 1*.

The `Dockerfile` generates the app image and is quite simple:

```
FROM busybox

COPY ./app /var/www/app
VOLUME /var/www/app/uploads
```

The generated image is pushed to Docker Hub on the `michaelperrin/app-test` repository.

On my server where the app is deployed, I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    image: michaelperrin/app-test:0.1.0
    working_dir: /var/www/app
    volumes:
      - /var/www/app

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.11
    volumes_from:
      - app
    working_dir: /var/www/app
```

It defines two containers:

- The app image.
- A Nginx server, that has access to the app files.

The app is run with the `docker-compose up -d` command.

Running `docker-compose exec nginx cat test-file.txt` will therefore display:

> Hello 1

Now, suppose I do the following steps:

1. Update the content of `file.txt` with `Hello 2` on my local machine.
2. Build a new image of my app (that copies the new version of `file.txt`)
3. Tag it and push it on Docker Hub as version `0.2.0`.
4. Change my `docker-compose.yml` file on the server to tell that I now use `michaelperrin/app-test:0.2.0` for my app.
5. Run `docker-compose up -d` (and `docker-compose restart` to be sure).

Then the terminal outputs:

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for michaelperrin/app-test:0.2.0
Recreating apptest_app_1
Recreating apptest_nginx_1
```

**And here is my problem:**

If I run `docker-compose exec nginx cat test-file.txt` it will still display *Hello 1*, **and not** *Hello 2*.

The only solution I found was to do the following:

```
docker-compose stop app
docker-compose rm app
docker-compose up -d
```

Is there any better solution?

The problem with the `rm` solution is that it will remove all other files that could have been created inside the `app` container by my app, in the `/var/www/app/uploads` directory (despite the fact it is declared as a volume in the `Dockerfile`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think (and really hope) that this is not possible. You create an instance (container) from your image with the state it has in the moment as it was built. You'd have unintended side effects when the creation of a new image has an effect on the containers.

Therefore you should remove the old containers and build fresh ones with the new image.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I understand the point. Should I share the uploads with the host to keep them?

Comment: The philosophy behind a container is that you can always throw it away. So I would store the uploads in a different location to keep them save. The host could be one solution (think of [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/)).

Comment: Your runtime/application container is supposed to be removed on update/upgrade that is where the Volume containers come in picture.

Comment: But that also means that you always loose the complete container configuration. That doesn't look clever to me, especially for containers with multiple images/volumes. Furthermore it makes automatic security updates very complicated.